# How to constraint a UILabel between two neighbors with truncation?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I've got a `UILabel` with variable length content, when the content is long I want the text to be truncated. This part works:

[image]

However if the text is short then this is how it appears:

[image]

I don't understand why the start of the text is shifted to the right - because the text is left aligned and there is a 8.5 constraint between it leading edge and the `UILabel's` to its left trailing edge:

[image]

[image]

When the text is short, why is it being shifted to the right?

How can I get it to be aligned to the left and be truncated when its too long to fit between the `UILabel` on the left and the disclosure indicator to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two labels. One says “Comment” and the other says “Short text”. These together are not enough to fill the horizontal space available, so UIKit stretches one to fill the space. It's stretching the “Comment” label but you want it to stretch the “Short text” label instead.

To prevent it from stretching “Comment”, increase the horizontal content hugging priority of the “Comment” label to 750.